# Easiest way to fix ghost clicks in jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, touch

I can't seem to find any straightforward way of fixing this? I can't wrap my head around [Google's Fast Buttons](https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons) approach. So if anyone has an alternative, that would be really nice.

The *ghost clicks* I'm talking about is referring to the touch on a button or something that triggers it multiple times. For example, clicking a button that will show `alert("hello");` will show that said alert box 2 or sometimes even 5 times.

This is part of my code that handles button pressing. I omitted some parts but basically, that's the mechanism that handles presses on the "add" button.

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
    var db = window.openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "MyDB", 1000000);

    var url = window.location.href;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    switch (filename) {
        case "index.html":
            $("#add").tap(function(e){
                if ($("#info").val() == "") {
                    navigator.notification.alert("The info cannot be blank!", function(){}, "Error", "Okay, got it!");
                } else {
                    db.transaction(addToDb, errorCB, addedToDb);
                }
            });
            break;
        case "sample.html":
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: You should show come code, what event are you binding to? Are you delegating event handlers?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a standard event binding happening inside of a delegated event binding. That means that the inner-binding will be bound every time the outer-event fires.

So basically you're re-binding your `tap` event handler each time the `pagebeforeshow` fires for any pseudo-page. Each time you navigate to another page you're creating another inner-binding so you're getting multiple alerts.

A good fix is to create a delegated event handler for the `pageinit` page-event and do the inner-binding in that event handler. The `pageinit` event only fires once per pseudo-page so you won't keep adding more event handlers unnecessarily.

For Example:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '.ui-page',function(){
    var db       = window.openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "MyDB", 1000000),
        url      = window.location.href,
        filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    switch (filename) {
        case "index.html":
            $("#add").tap(function(e){
                if ($("#info").val() == "") {
                    navigator.notification.alert("The info cannot be blank!", function(){}, "Error", "Okay, got it!");
                } else {
                    db.transaction(addToDb, errorCB, addedToDb);
                }
            });
            break;
        case "sample.html":
            break;
    }
});
```

You'll notice I used `.on()` for my delegated event handler instead of the depreciated `.live()`.