# What's the appropriate way to attach button click events in jQuery Mobile for different pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12826004/1023230) but apparently, I still get ghost clicks with it.

For example, I'm using the following code inside page1.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageinit', '.ui-page',function(){
        $("#someButtonForPage1").click(function(){
            $.mobile.changePage("page2.html");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then on page 2, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pageinit', '.ui-page',function(){
        $("#someButtonForPage2").click(function(){
            $.mobile.changePage("page1.html");
        });
    });
</script>
```

As for the pages, they merely contain a header, a content body (with the button element inside) and a footer. What happens is clicking on the buttons will make the page transition to each other at least a couple of times. Meaning I still get ghost clicks.

What will absolutely fix this?

Comment: Have you looked at the Multi-page layout? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a common jQuery mobile problem. Before you bind a event on anything you need to check if that event is already bind to that element. For example, button with the 2 click/tap events on it will execute wanted action 2 times.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541888/jquery-mobile-div-as-link-and-back-button-issue/13542166#13542166) you will find my answer to same question.

My first example uses Event filter, and you can find it [here](http://www.codenothing.com/archives/jquery/event-filter/), example is [here](http://www.codenothing.com/archives/jquery/event-filter/).